# I can't make sudo su on old version CentOS with LDAP

Tags: centos, ldap, sudo

I configured many servers with the option to make "sudo su" with ldap users, and works fine.

But in 2 servers (CentOS 5.7 and 5.5) this option show me an error:

```
    [user] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I can't understand why the configuration don't works.

All the servers have the same configuration, i only add this line

```
    sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=dominio,dc=root
```

My sensation is that the server can't ask to SUDOers LDAP.

Somebody  can give me an idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Version CentOS that this configuration works fine: 5.3,5.4,5.8, etc...

Comment: Have you verified that the version of `sudo` installed on the affected machines was compiled with LDAP support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

A solution very stupid :D

In this moment, in

```
   /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Don't appear the next line:

```
    sudoers:  files ldap
```

I wrote this line and sudoers works fine.

In my other machines, this options appears automatically.

Thanks for all!